# Rank of sum of matrix and arbitrarily small matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Suppose I have an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with full rank. Let $B$ be another $n\times n$ matrix and let $c>0$ be a constant. Can we always find a constant $c>0$ sufficiently small such that
$$
A + cB
$$
also has full rank?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because the determinant is a continuous function of the matrix entries. If it's not zero then it's not zero for nearby matrices.

**Edit** in response to comment.

This is true for rectangular matrices too. To prove it, note that Gaussian elimination produces the reduced row echelon form $R$ of $M$ by multiplication on the right by an invertible matrix $A$. Now $M$ is full rank if and only if $R$ has a full rank (identity) matrix in its upper left corner. You can perturb that corner and keep it full rank. Since multiplication by $A$ is a continuous bijection, matrices near $M$ will be full rank.

Comment: Great, thank you for the response. Do you have a similar argument for non square matrices?

Comment: Yes. See my edit.

Comment: Does it hold even if $B$ is not full rank?

Comment: @CloudJR Yes. The rank of $B$ is irrelevant. Read the proof sketch in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, valid over any field with more than $n+1$ elements:

Since $A$ is full rank and square, it has an inverse. Then
$$\det(A+cB)=\det(A(I+cA^{-1}B))=\det(A)\det(I+cA^{-1}B).$$

Since $\det(A)\neq0$, $A+cB$ is full rank iff $\det(I+cA^{-1}B)\neq0$.

Now, if $c\neq0$ then $\det(I+cA^{-1}B)=c^n\det(c^{-1}I+A^{-1}B)$, so $A+cB$ is full rank iff $$\det(c^{-1}I+A^{-1}B)\neq0.$$

This happens iff $-c^{-1}\not\in$Spec$(A^{-1}B)$. So there are at most $n$ values of $c$ which do not give full rank.