# Perturbation of injective map.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, linear-transformations

I've got stuck on a result I am not able to prove. I will extrapolate it from its context:

> Let$\space$ $f$  be a linear injective map between $\mathbb{R}^n $ and $\mathbb{R}^m $ with $n \leq m$ and $g$ be a linear isomorphism in  $\mathbb{R}^n $.
>
> Let $ || \space ||$ be some consistent $m \times n$ matrix norm. Then exists $\epsilon >0$ such that for every $A$, $||A|| < \epsilon$ we have that:
>
> $f+Ag$ is still injective.

Can someone help?

Thanks :)

Comment: Related, possible  duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2485822/rank-of-sum-of-matrix-and-arbitrarily-small-matrix/2485826#2485826

Comment: How is $Ag$ defined?

Comment: Maybe it could be helpful to know that you can represent $f$ as $f(x)=\textbf {Ax}$, with $\textbf A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ and $r(A)=n$.

Comment: @Paul Frost, I meant (Ag)(x)=Ag(x) where this latter is the usual multiplication between matrix and vector. Thanks to everyone

Comment: Then you identify the matrix $\mathbf{A} $ with the linear map $\mathbf{x} \mapsto \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}$ which is okay. The linear isomorphism $g$ is expendable. The function $\mathbf{A} \mapsto \mathbf{A}g$ establishes a linear automorphism on the vector space of all $(m \times n)$-matrices. You have $f + \mathbf{A} g = f + \mathbf{A'}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $f$ is injective, it is bounded below. Indeed, as $f:\mathbb R^n\to \text{Im}\,f$ is bijective, it is invertible (we are in finite dimension, so every linear map is continuous). Or, since $f$ achieves its max and min in the unit ball, there exist constants $c,d$ with $c\|x\|\leq\|fx\|\leq d\|x\|$ for all $x$.

Now, if $\|A\|<c/\|g\|$ and $(f+Ag)x=0$, we have 
$$
0=\|fx+Agx\|\geq \|fx\|-\|Agx\|\geq c\|x\|-\|A\|\,\|g\|\,\|x\|
=(c-\|A\|\,\|g\|)\,\|x\|.
$$
As $c-\|A\|\,\|g\|>0$, we get $x=0$, and $f+Ag$ is injective.

In the argument above I'm using for $A$ the operator norm induced by the norms in $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$. But since in a finite-dimensional space all norms are equivalent, we can replace the norm by any other, at the cost of changing the $\epsilon$ a bit.

Comment: Glad I could help :)